# Ethernet connected but no internet access

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, internet

I am very very new to this all and over my head. I am hosting Ubuntu on a VM Virtual Box to host my shiny dashboard. It was all working and now suddenly I do not have internet access inside the Virtual Box which is causing it to not host my dashboard and I have know idea why.

Below are some outputs, please let me know if you need more or some other piece of information. I am using a NAT connection. Please note this is all on a company computer so I am limited to what I can do (i.e. reset routers, etc.).

Comment: can you ping from your host the google ip address ? `ping 172.217.10.110`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74561/discussion-between-rebrec-and-kevin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your logs, your NAT is working fine, but your company blocks outgoing ICMP (ping) packets, this is why you do not manage to test Internet connectivity using *ping*.

You are using a proxy server to access to the web on your Host computer, if you want to access the web within your VM, you must setup the appropriate proxy server, port, user, password.

In your VM, on your browser (Firefox) go to the [Connection Settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox).
Configure the proxy settings in **Manual proxy configuration**.

Then enter the expected parameter (HTTP Proxy, Port...)

Then you should have access to the Web (if your corporate proxy authentication scheme is compatible with your Linux VM)